# In javascript what is the video equivalent of "new Audio( )"

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

In Javascript you can access the HTML-5 audio object like this:

```
var audio = new Audio('nameOfFile.mp3');
```

But the equivalent syntax for the video element doesn't seem to work (I'm on Chrome).

```
var video = new Video('nameOfFile.ogg');
```

I'm curious if there *is* an equivalent object for the video tag that I can access via this simple **new** syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't one yet, but you can create one the long way around:

```
var video = document.createElement("video");
video.setAttribute("src", "nameOfFile.ogg");
```

Answer (score 6):

Just in case you need, I have one, quite similar to the `new Audio()` thing...

```
function Video(src, append) {
  var v = document.createElement("video");
  if (src != "") {
    v.src = src;
  }
  if (append == true) {
    document.body.appendChild(v);
  }
  return v;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var video = new Video("YOUR_VIDEO_URL", true);
// do whatever you want...
video.height = 280;
video.width = 500;
video.controls = "controls";
video.play();
```