# How to correctly create HTML5 audio and video with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

I checked out the [w3c specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element) and it seems that in JavaScript we can create HTML5 audio in 2 ways, whereas for HTML5 video there's just one way:

Audio:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
```

or

```
var audio = new Audio();
```

Video:

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
```

But is it true that for HTML5 video there is no equivalent constructor like `new Video()`?

//edit: seems like in [March 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286407/in-javascript-what-is-the-video-equivalent-of-new-audio?rq=1) there was no equivalent..

Comment: You can also create audio from an `AudioContext` with the Web Audio API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, as of now there is no other way to dynamically create a video in javascript other than using:

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
```